# Is there no way to scale GtkImage display through css?

Tags: css, themes, scale, gtk3

Gtk-3.0 now uses css-like stylesheets to render the UI.

But I would like to scale down a `GtkImage` thanks to css ?

is that possible ? I can't find any `width`/`height` property.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with GTK CSS when displaying the image in a `GtkImage` widget. However, you can do something very similar by using a blank `GtkFrame` and setting its `background-image` property in your CSS, instead of loading the image in code. Then you can control the scale and position using the `background-size`, `background-position`, etc. properties.

Comment: Ok, but you need to changed more than the CSS (change the application structure), and if your application is using images that are not part of your static assets, this solution doesn't seem applicable. But thanks for the tip, some people might have some use of this solution.